# how to get an image actual width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get real image width and height with JavaScript in Safari/Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Is there a way to know the true width and height of an image using jQuery when the image is scaled down in css - without any extra data of dimensions -  any link or code example would be helpful thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: **[Get real image width and height with JavaScript in Safari/Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)** and **[Get image width and height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799710/get-image-width-and-height)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`.

```
var domElement = $('yourImage')[0]; // or document.getElementById('yourImageId');
domElement.naturalWidth
domElement.naturalHeight
```

Comment: If that works, then I think it's a better solution than the one suggested in [that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", imgSrc).load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   
        pic_real_height = this.height;          
    });
```

The thing is, you can only access image true width and height when the image is loaded, u could also load the image without any container to some place where you can not see it and ask for ("img").css('width'), but i think this is a more elegant way to do it. Hope this is helpful.