# Get the size of image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get the dimensions of image. Here is the code...

The HTML:

```
<img class="edit-img about-img" src="images/box-model.jpg">
```

The JavaScript:

```
function getDimension () {
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName('about-img');

    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
}

window.onload = getDimension;
```

It say's that the variable 'width' & 'height' is undefined. I also tried using `img.width` & `img.height`.

Comment: Is this the actual image height/width or the displayed height/width?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The displayed height/width is what size the image is on the screen (as the styles to the image can change the dimensions). The actual height/width - or natural height/widht - are what the image is as a file.

Comment: I want the natural height/width.

Comment: Then this answer might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729567/how-to-get-an-image-actual-width-and-height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does just that - get element**s** by class name.

It doesn't return a single Node - even if there is only one element with that class name - but rather a NodeList of all the elements.

What you'd be looking for is something like this:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('about-img')[0];

var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

However, hard-coding the index like this assumes that there is only one image with that class name. That may not always be true, and if it isn't, then just taking the first element probably won't get you what you're looking for. In this case, I would give the image an ID:

```
<img class="edit-img about-img" id="my-image" src="images/box-model.jpg">
```

After you've done this, you can use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), which works as you expected `getElementsByClassName()` to:

```
var img = document.getElementById('my-image');

var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the element by it's `id` attribute, to get the image you are referring to.

```js
function getDimension () {
    var img = document.getElementById('myId');
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
}

window.onload = getDimension();
```

```html
<img id="myId" class="edit-img about-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/znazc9ap/)

```
function getDimension () {
    var img = document.getElementById('imageId');
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
    alert(width);
}

window.onload = getDimension();
```

Just have to use an ID instead of class name in your JavaScript.  Check the fiddle.