# jQuery callback called too early?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function load(toLoad, area){
    $(area).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" class="center" />');
    loadContent();
    function loadContent() {
        $(area).load(toLoad,'',sorter())
    };
    function sorter() {
        alert('s');
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({
            widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    };
    return false
};
```

When the load function is called, the alert shows when the loading image is shown, rather than after it has finished loading.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: where's your load(toload,area) call ?

Comment: You may also be interested in the answers here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: @Soufiane Hassou, it was somewhere else in the code. I didn't see a reason for including it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the syntax is a little off for this.

instead of

```
function loadContent() {
    $(area).load(toLoad,'',sorter())
};
```

try

```
function loadContent() {
    $(area).load(toLoad,'',sorter)
};
```

Comment: Perfect. I don't know why it seemed to work with the brackets in other places though... Maybe I just didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Move your function definitions outside of the load function.  It should look like

```
function load(toLoad, area){
    $(area).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" class="center" />');
    loadContent();
}

function loadContent() {
        $(area).load(toLoad,'',sorter())
}

function sorter() {
        alert('s');
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    };
    return false
}
```

Comment: ha! I knew that looked wrong, I actually got the code from somewhere else and couldn't figure out why they had it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (wrap the call to sorter() in the load function in an anonymous function)

```
function load(toLoad, area){
    $(area).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" class="center" />');
    loadContent();
    function loadContent() {
        $(area).load(toLoad,'',function() {sorter()})
    };
    function sorter() {
        alert('s');
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    };
    return false
};
```