# jQuery .load importing special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, character-encoding

I currently have a mind boggling error. I am using the .load function in jQuery to load images for a slideshow and getting a bunch of errors below by img tag that i am importing the url to.  I have done my best to demonstrate my function and markup below.  I do not get an error in any modern browsers but IE gives me errors

```
     $('a').click(function(e){
    $(trainFull).fadeOut(400, function(){
         jQuery(trainFull[0]).load('http://img.jpg", function(){
          jQuery(this).hide().attr('src', 'http://img.jpg").fadeIn(400);
   });



<img alt="Train Full" src="http://img.jpg" ">
<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">�����JFIF���d�d�����Ducky�����(�����Adobe�d���������--etc, etc, etc/>
```

Comment: +1 for '...any modern browsers but IE gives me errors'. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to pre-load the image using jQuery's XMLHttpRequest wrapper ([`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). This is... [unlikely to work well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest).

What you're seeing is IE trying to interpret binary image data as text (with predictably poor results), jQuery trying to stuff them into your `<img>` element, and IE trying to display them. While this probably does manage to pre-cache the image, it's the wrong tool for the job... and as you've demonstrated, a tool that can *fail badly*.

Fortunately, there are easier ways. Most browsers provide built-in support for loading images and notifying a script when they have loaded. For instance:

```
$('<img />') // detached image, used to pre-load
    .attr('src', 'http://img.jpg') // tell it which image to load
    .load(function() // attach a callback to inform us when it's loaded
    {
      // within the callback, "this" refers to the temporary image element
      // that has just finished loading its source

      // now that the image is in the cache,
      $(trainFull[0])
        .attr('src', this.src) // let our on-page image display it
        .fadeIn(400); // and show that
    });
```

If you want to learn more about this, I recommend starting with: [jQuery ajax images preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798995/jquery-ajax-images-preload).

Comment: Thanks shog9.  I now know exactly how .load() works and understand my error.  Thanks again you helped immensely!