# jQuery find height of an image even if it is not set in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have, what I think is, a strange issue. I am running a simple query that finds the largest image on a page. Here is some test data - all images are 32x32 but one is sized to 300x300.

```
<img src="app/assets/images/icons/blue.png" />
<img src="app/assets/images/icons/error.png"/>
<img src="app/assets/images/icons/info.png" height="300" width="300"/>
```

If I run a simple query like this:

```
$('img').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).height());
    });
```

I will get `0,0,300` — and not `32,32,300`.

Can anyone point me to a better method of finding the size the image is being rendered at?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is "natively" sized, i.e. no width or height are present in the HTML, you'll need to wait for the image to load before you know its size. I use this:

```
jQuery("img").each(function(){
    var img = jQuery(this);
    if (img.attr("complete")) {
        console.log(img.height());
    } else {
        img.load(function(){
            console.log(img.height());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you do it after the image is ready in `$(img).load()`, then it will work. Try JavaScript to verify:

```
function iLoad(isrc) {
var oImg = new Image();
oImg.src = isrc;
if (oImg.complete) {
window.alert(oImg.src + ' ' + oImg.width + ' x ' + oImg.height);
```