# jQuery IE7 on-the-fly images

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, image

The simplified version of the problem I am seeing in IE7 can be demonstrated using [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

On a page loaded with jQuery, I open [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (via bookmarket) and I enter the following:

```
image = $('<img src="http://example.com/boofar.jpg" border="12" 
                    width="95" height="95" title="Booya">')[0];
```

and the result echoed is:

```
<img title="Booya" contentEditable="inherit" start="fileopen" 
                    loop="1" src="http://example.com/boofar.jpg" border="12">
```

Where are the **width** and **height** attributes?
Furthermore,

```
 image.width;
```

and

```
 image.attributes.width.value;
```

return 0 and "0".

Seen this with both jQuery 1.2.6 as well as 1.4.2. It does the right thing in IE8 and FF.

Any ideas where those attributes went? Very annoying....

Comment: you can do 

table = $('<table width="95" height="95" title="Booya" />')[0]

and get

<table title="Booya" contentEditable="inherit" height="95" width="95">

so what gives?

Comment: @Scott - I'm not seeing this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/UGzED/ I get: `<IMG title=Booya height=95 src="http://example.com/boofar.jpg" width=95 border=12>` for the result.

Comment: @Nick - huh - verrrry interesting . lemme study what's different cause I don't get it.. seems if you insert the img into the div, the attrs re-appear ? .. weirdness .. tnx for commenting

Comment: Okay i'm even more baffled .. in my example, image.outerHTML gives <IMG title=Booya height=95 src="http://example.com/boofar.jpg" width=95 border=12> but image.width gives 0 .. !!?wtf!? .. btw @Nick - thanks for the jsfiddle resource / useful!

Comment: @Scott - Elements don't get height/width until inserted into the DOM, things like padding or other style rules affect the value, so what the height is depends on where the element is inserted.

Comment: i want to to get the value of width and height attribute values as specified in the HTML. I am not interested in the width / height of the loaded image - and I agree I won't know THOSE values til the image has been fetched. But those *attribute* values MUST be maintained *somewhere* in the element irregardless of whether the src has been loaded. As far as I can tell digging into the DOM they seem to be held solely in the outerHTML field and not maintained anywhere else ...

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better results using jQuery to create the image attributes directly:

```
var $image = jQuery('<img />', 
       {   
           title: "Booya",
           src:   "http://example.com/boofar.jpg",
           css: {
                  border: "12px",
                  width : "95px",
                  height: "95px"
                }
      });
```

You'll run into issues obtaining correct width/height with webkit browsers when it's set explicitly vs. it's actual width/height. You might want to take a peek at this: [Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Comment: well yeah but -- this simplified problem represents a issue I am seeing in a generalized HTML analyzer I've built. I am not specifically needing to make IMAGES by themselves. Instead I am using jQuery to wrap an arbitrary HTML string and then traversing the result set to figure the structure out..