# jquery .width() chrome and safari problem

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari

I have set in css the height of an image to a certain value and the width modifies automatically so that the aspect ratio is preserved. I'm using the .width() jquery function to get the width of the image after the css resized the image. in Firefox and internet explorer this works great but in chrome and safari the width returned is always 0 for each image. the code that i am using is the following:

```
var total=0; 
var widthdiv=0;
$(function(){
    $('.thumb').each(function(){
       widthdiv=$(this).width();
       total+=widthdiv;
       alert(widthdiv); //added so i can see what value is returned.
    });
});
```

and the css for the images:

```
#poze img{
    height:80px;
    width:auto;
    border:0px;
    padding-right:4px;    
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome).  I think yours is the same issue.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `document.ready` (which you're currently using) images may or may not be loaded, if they're not in cache they probably *aren't* loaded.  Instead use the [`window.onload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onload) when the images *are* loaded, like this:

```
var total=0; 
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.thumb').each(function() {
    total += $(this).width();
  });
});
```

Comment: width() is also not giving me right values, How to solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650991/phantom-height-when-specifying-the-width-of-a-li-using-jquery