# Phantom height when specifying the width of a LI using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

On  a simple `ul` and `li` structure like this:

```
<div id="middle">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>
                bridal
            </a>                    
        </li>
        //....
    </ul>
</div>
```

`ul` is displayed as table and `li` as table cell. I am using jquery to fix the width of the li, after they are loaded on the DOM. This is to stabilize the width when font family is changed.

But, at chrome I get a phantom height and the the width of `a` is 10px+ more than the jQuery calculates.

[image: Illustration]

Help me fix these: http://jsfiddle.net/qK8Yr/

Note: If I remove the code to set the width, the [phantom height](http://jsfiddle.net/qK8Yr/1/) goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following CSS for this class

http://jsfiddle.net/qK8Yr/3/

```
nav#mainNavigation a
{
cursor: pointer;
font-family: 'Verdana';
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
padding: 3px 0px !important;

}
```

Comment: hi check the custom div

Answer (score 0):

It adds 5px left padding, 5px right padding and 2px of border width from your css. if you can not find which css effects. comment back

```
    nav#mainNavigation > div > ul > li > .relContainer > a {
padding: 7px 5px;
}
```

the  tag take this css