# Get True Dimensions of an Image with JQuery

Tags: jquery, image

Given a list of image paths how can I iterate through them and find the actual image dimensions?  I assume I have to insert them into the DOM without width or height properties and do a .width and .height on them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome Looks similar.

Comment: Have you tried width() and height()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var paths = ['/path/image.png', 'somewhere/page.jpg'];

$.each(paths, function(i, path) {
    var img = new Image();

    $(img).load(function() {

        var width = img.width,
            height = img.height;

        alert(width + ' × ' + height);

    });

    img.src = path;

});
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/jseny/).

Comment: I have a question about that code. Yes, it works, but how are the width and height extracted from the Image object before the img.src veriable is set?

Comment: @Michael - the width and height are extracted "after" the img.src is set. The block of code right before the line `img.src = path;` is just the binding of the event handler to the _load_ event. The event handler doesn't run until the _load_ event happens, which is afterward.