# Get image size using JQuery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

please tell me how to get image size of all images in the page using jquery or javascript

Comment: You want the total size summed up? each image separate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only size you can get is the visible size. [clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientheight) are two DOM properties which do this. Example:

```
var image = document.getElementById("id");
var width = image.clientWidth;
var height = image.clientHeight;
```

If you're using jQuery, you can simply use [$.width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [$.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
var width = $("id").width();
var height = $("id").height();
```

So, to get the size of all images, loop them through:

```
$("img").each(function()
{
    console.log(this.width());
    console.log(this.height());
});
```

If you need the real size, please see this question [Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Comment: I have a form to upload an image, is there any way to get image dimensions on the client side before I process it on server side.

Comment: @SIFE Yes, it is possible in newer browsers. Please ask this in a new question.

Comment: See my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390167/how-to-get-image-dimensions-on-the-client-side) pls. stackoverflow must star thinking on url shortening service.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').each(function() {
   $(this).width(); // current image's width
   $(this).height(); // current image's height
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> please tell me how to get image size
>   of all images in the page using jquery
>   or javascript

You can use [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method of jQuery:

```
$('img').each(function(){
   alert('width=' + $(this).width() + '\nHeight=' + $(this).height());
});
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/width/
- http://api.jquery.com/height/