# load event with jquery fails in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

i've written a jquery plugin to scale a image up an back down. in ie 8 the load event of the large version of the image fails. i tried like thsi:

```
        var fullImage = container.find(options.fullSelector);
        fullImage.attr('src', fullImageUrl).bind('load', function() {
            content.fadeOut(options.fadeSpeed, function(){
                if(slideContent.size()){
                    slideContent.slideUp(options.resizeSpeed, function(){
                        smallImage.hide();
                        fullImage.show();
                        fullImage.parent().andSelf().stop().animate({ width: options.fullWidth + 'px' }, options.resizeSpeed);
                    });
                }
                else{
                    smallImage.hide();
                    fullImage.show();
                    fullImage.parent().andSelf().stop().animate({ width: options.fullWidth + 'px' }, options.resizeSpeed);
                }
            });
        });
```

the error says: Object doesn't support property or method.

what am i doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: After the first line, type `alert(fullImage.length);` to determine if find is actually finding something. IE8 does have some quirks when it comes to traversal.

Comment: on a second note, IE8 isn't happy loading anything. I am surprised it even allows to download other browsers:D

Comment: i that with: if(fullImage.size()). isn't that the same? about the loading: i've nver had problems...

Comment: fullimage.size() is exactly the same. size() is a function call that returns this.length. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set the `load` handler first, then set the `src`.

```
fullImage.bind('load', function() {
   ...
}).attr('src', fullImageUrl);
```

Comment: I was having a slightly different issue than the OP where my load handler was never firing, but this fixed it for me too. Can anyone help explain why this works? My guess is that IE might pull the image from cache before the load handler is added. Related: http://davidwalsh.name/image-load-event

Comment: Loading the image happens asynchronously immediately after the `src` attribute is set. You have no way no know when it will finish, so it could be finished before the `load` event handler has been bound.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```js
var test = function($what) {
  $('#debug').html('Image loaded: '+$what.width+' x '+$what.height);
  console.log($what);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Random image
var src = "http://placehold.it/300x" + Math.round(Math.random() * (310 - 100) + 100);
</script>
<div id="debug">Image loading:</div>    
<img onload="test(this)" id="img" />

<script>
$('#img')[0].src = src;
</script>
```