# jquery code not working in IE8 or older

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Can anybody tell me why this snippet of code doesn't work in IE8 or older please?
It doesn't throw an error, just doesn't seem to run.

```
$('<img/>')
.attr('src', $('.my_div img:first').attr('src'))
.load(function(){
   console.log('hello');
       alert('hello');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does not work? As Far as I know, the IE7 und IE 6 has not got a console output. For IE8 I'm not sure to 100% that it is has got one either.

Comment: surely u only need to do $("img") not $("<img/>")  ?

Comment: Did you try removing the console.log?

Comment: is the console object declared somewhere?? as far as i know console is an object of firebug and works in firefox when present...

Comment: Sorry. I'm debugging this in IE9 running in IE8 mode. So yes it does have a console. I've edited the original post to include an alert too. Still the same. Doesn't run.

Comment: @Neil: That would change the source of all images in the page instead of creating an new image element.

Comment: @optimusprime619, console is implemented by the browser. Chrome and opera also has it without needing plugins.

Comment: @jSang Thanks for the info...always good to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE8 the load event happens before you set the event handler. Set the load event before setting the source attribute:

```
$('<img/>').load(function(){
  console.log('hello');
}).attr('src', $('.my_div img:first').attr('src'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/GRKJE/

Related: [load event with jquery fails in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921712/load-event-with-jquery-fails-in-ie-8)