# Gather elements native width and height before adjusting size

Tags: jquery, height, width, native, resolution

Can I gather an image or video's native resolution in jQuery? I'm going to manipulate it's size later on, but need a reference to it's original res.

I've seen a few tags such as `rootElement.height()` but no documentation on it.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome so your best bet would be to head over there :)

Comment: Kinda sorta. Saw that question.. the solution doesn't stick when working with cached images and I'll be dealing with videos as well.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [this](http://api.jquery.com/height/)? You may need to expand on your original question.  If you want video resolution the javascript will be player dependent.

Comment: That looks about right.. But once I manipulate the size of the object .height() will return it's adjusted size, not it's native size. Do you know what I mean? I'm looking to turn the native height and width into variables to use into a function.

Comment: Yeah, you are talking about the actual resolution.  What player are you using?

Comment: HTML5 video with img fallback (no flash), which is why I need to gather the object's original size whether video or image