# Can I preserve the aspect ratio of an image element in an SVG document?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG document with an emebedded image element like so:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <image xlink:href="hannibal.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="200" height='200' />
</svg>
```

I can't know ahead of time the width and height of the linked image.

How can I set the width of the image to be the same as the viewBox, and allow the height to autoscale?

Failing this, can I align the image content to the top of the image element?

Comment: Have you tried setting width/height/both to 100% or just removing them?

Comment: If you remove them the image is not displayed. Set them to 100% and they gain the width and height of the viewbox with the image content centered inside.

Comment: Well, there is kinda similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884513/how-to-get-the-real-unscaled-size-of-an-embedded-image-in-the-svg-document

Is the first answer any help to you?

Comment: Perhaps JavaScript is the solution. It just seems like there ought to be an SVG solution to embedding an image with the correct width and height.

Comment: By autoscale do you mean that it must cover the svg doc?

Comment: Ideally I would like the SVG doc to be the same size as the image. The reason is that I want to be able to mask the image with a complex SVG shape. I would settle for simply ensuring the image sat correctly at the top of the svg. I suspect the solution is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be at the top of the viewBox, rather than the centre, you just have to set `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"`.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <image xlink:href="hannibal.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin"/>
</svg>
```

This should work as long as the height is never greater than the width.