# Fade image position

Tags: jquery, image, mouseover, fade

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/userfiles/test.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/userfiles/test2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Each of these image is 950 pixels wide and 600 pixels in height.

The first 300 pixel in height is the mouse-out image and the last 300 pixel is the mouse-over image I want to fade over. Is this possible?

I have this CSS to control what image to show:

```
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
ul li { width: 950px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
ul li img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This code just moves the last 300 pixels of the image up, **but instead of moving it I want to opacity fade the image over the "other":.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("ul li img").mouseover(function () {
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    { top: "-300px" },
                    { duration: 300 })
            })
            .mouseout(function () {
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    { top: "0" },
                    { duration: 300 })
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Are you looking for some opacity feature depend on the mouse position?

Comment: Yes I want to fade the last 300 pixels of the image over the other on hover.

Comment: Do you want to fade top image over bottom only? What should be done when you mouseover bottom image?

Comment: I need to fade the "bottom" image (last 300 pixels) over the "top" image (first 300 pixels) and when I move the mouse out it should fade top the "top" image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/v73AG/16/

Comment: BNot exactly. It should not move, but cross-fade the "two" images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just finished implementing this, thanks for presenting a nice and reasonably short excercise.

**[First off, see the end result here](http://jsfiddle.net/xMeRf/)**.

Implementation notes:

1. **Consider changing your markup if possible**. This would have been so much easier (I would go so far as to say trivial) if you used the image as a `background-image` rather than a standalone `img` element, and it would also be more performant.
2. The solution works by adding a "sister" `div` for each `img` element and styling it appropriately. The most important is setting its `background-image` property, which allows us to show only the desired half of the picture.
3. The solution requires dynamically calculating the size of the source image, which I did using the [solution presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome).

Comment: I know the background image position would be MUCH better. But I needed this for a special case. This works just PERFECT! Awesome!

Comment: I have a odd problem, there is a short 'blink' effect on this test: http://detnyesort.dk.web111.curanetserver.dk/work.aspx - how is that possible?

Comment: @meep: No idea really -- I 'll take a look when I find some time, but no promises :)

Comment: No need! I missed some style sheet! Ignore previous request. You rock! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got the idea. The working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/avall/RMWt8/1/

The solution uses `overflow` style and play with layers (`z-index`).

It should be slightly upgraded because of center line bug when you go with your mouse from bottom to top but you should get the idea.