# Animate left not working properly in webkit(Chrome/Safari)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an issue with a jquery image slide plugin i'm working on where the images scroll left creating the slideshow.  IE and FireFox work fine but Safari/Chrome(WebKit) just wont work.

This the call in question

```
    $(".nav li").live("click", function () {
    if (lastSelected != null) $(lastSelected).removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    place = parseInt($(this).text());
    if (place > last) {
        offset = parseInt(place - last);
        direction = "-=";
    }
    else {
        offset = parseInt(last - place);
        direction = "+=";
    }
```

// this is where it only works for IE and FF

```
    $(".slideshow img").each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: direction + (offset * imageWidth) + "px"
        });
    });
```

// Am I doing something wrong hmm?

```
    reset = true;
    last = place;
    lastSelected = $(this);
}).css("cursor", "pointer");
```

Comment: can you give us a demo using an online tool like  http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can test it more easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been doing some debugging an have found that the offset * imageWidth stays 0 in Chrome!

Solution found:

1. [Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)
2. http://name1price.com/how-to-get-customers-with-singapore-web-design-basic/jquery-tutorials/149-jquery-get-image-height-or-width-returns-0-problem-.html

These two sources help fix the "jQuery get image height or width returns 0 problem" which was the initial problem.  I am now using the fix found in the first solution above and that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

what is this `lastSelected`

are you sure

```
$(lastSelected).removeClass("selected");
```

is working ???

because

```
lastSelected is an `object` not an attribute
```

try this (assume you have an id attribute)

```
lastSelected = $(this).attr('id');
```

and

```
if (lastSelected != null) $('#'+lastSelected).removeClass("selected");
```

Comment: Thanks Kanish,

As you can see in the code lastSelect gets changed to $(this) which is the current object, on the next run it is the last object.  This works fine.

So I have been doing some debugging an have found that the (offset * imageWidth) stays 0 in WebKit browsers(Safari/Chrome), I have modified the code in question a little which is now live here: http://garruu.dyndns.org 

I don't understand why the value isn't working in WebKit browsers; so thats where i'm going to look, fingers crossed.

Comment: So some more debugging has found that imageWidth is not getting the image width in WebKit Browers.  I also found out that a WebKit fix would be to put the image width in the <img> tag.  I would prefer a dynamic solution and wont close this thread until I get a better solution.