# jquery get image width after src change

Tags: jquery, src, attr

my jquery code:

```
 img[i]='img-src';
 $("#popimage1").attr("src",img[i]);
 alert($("#popimage1").width());      //doesn't give the width of the current image, but it gives for the previous, and for first null
```

my html code:

```
 <img src="" id="popimage1"/>
```

so the concept is that i load different image src for each i with jquery,and then i do some calculations with the width and height. The problem is that i get the values for the image with the previous counter i. I have made a temporary solution, by putting

```
  $("#popimage1").hide();
  setTimeout(alert($("#popimage1").width(),2000);
  $("#popimage1").show();
```

But its not working always, and causes an unnecessary timeout.
instead of alert there is another function that uses img width and height, i just wrote alert for your convenience. Any help appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get real image width and height with Javascript in Safari/Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Comment: Have you tried using the answer there? It should serve your purposes.

Comment: well the question is a bit different but the first answer solves my problem ,now i see it again.. but i didn't realise it first time, anyway i think it will be good not to lock the topic since the question is alittle different.. thank you all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to wait for the image to load first.

Try this.

```
img[i] = "img-src";
$("#popimage1").attr("src", img[i]).load(function() {
  alert($("#popimage1").width());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the image source is asynchronous, therefore does not return immediately.

Try handling the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#popimage1").load(function() {
  alert($(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `.load` function has been deprecated [since jQuery 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/).
Use the `.on` function with the corresponding event name:

```js
$("#popimage1").on('load', function() {
    alert($(this).width());
})
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252711/2893053