# jquery iframe beforeunload control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a iframe and I have close button top of the right iframe and I want to make it active after load.but if it's not loaded I want to make it passive but I don't understand why my code doesn't work and actually my code is simply..

After iframe load my `makeActive` function is working and if it's not loading my `makePassive` is working with `onunload` js events..where is my fault ?

```js
function makePassive() {
  $("#kapat").attr("data-status", "pasif");
  $("#kapat").css("background-color", "#ddd");
  $("#request").prop("disabled", true);
}

function makeActive() {
  $("#kapat").attr("data-status", "aktif");
  $("#kapat").css("background-color", "#000");
  $("#request").prop("disabled", false);
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#iframe").load(function() {
    makeActive();
  });

  

  document.getElementById("iframe").onunload(makePassive());

  $(".kapat").on("click",function() {
    var status = $(this).attr("data-status");

    if (status == "aktif") {
      alert("it's active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.iframe-alan {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.kapat {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-alan">
<div class="kapat" id="kapat" data-status="aktif">X</div>
<iframe name="iframe" height="600" width="100%" id="iframe" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" src="https://anitur.com.tr"></iframe>
</div>
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="request" value="İstek Yap" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are going after. One of your issues was using the `.load` jquery event alias [which have been depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252711/1608016). I am assuming the goal is to get `alert("it's active")` to fire?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  function makePassive() {            
    $("#kapat").attr("data-status", "pasif");
    $("#kapat").css("background-color", "#ddd");
    $("#request").prop("disabled", true);
  }

  function makeActive() {
    $("#kapat").attr("data-status", "aktif");
    $("#kapat").css("background-color", "#000");
    $("#request").prop("disabled", false);
  }

  $('#iframe').on('load',function(){
    makeActive();
    $(".kapat").on("click",function() {
        var status = $(this).attr("data-status");

        if (status == "aktif") {
          alert("it's active");
        }
    });
  });
  $('#iframe').on('unload', function(){
      makePassive();
  });
});
```

```css
.iframe-alan {
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.kapat {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-alan">
<div class="kapat" id="kapat" data-status="aktif">X</div>
<iframe name="iframe" height="600" width="100%" id="iframe" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" src="https://anitur.com.tr"></iframe>
</div>
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" id="request" value="İstek Yap" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it beats me why you would want to name give your element an id of `iframe`, You should change this line

```
document.getElementById("iframe").onunload(makePassive());
```

to this

```
document.getElementById("iframe").onunload = makePassive;
```

or this

```
$("#iframe").unload(makePassive);
```

DOM event handlers don't have a similar signature to jQuery.

You should also change the initial color of your button to grey, so you can tell when it's done loading.

```
.kapat {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  background-color: #ddd; /* make it initially grey, then it changes to black when iframe loads */
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: tahoma;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe due to cross-origin restrictions you do not have access to hearing the `unload` event of iframe. That means that you will need to manage the state of the iframe manually.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var status = 'pasif';
    var frame =  document.getElementById("iframe");


    $('#iframe').on('load',function(){
        updateStatus();
        if (status == "aktif") { 
            $(".kapat").on("click",function() { 
                unloadIFrame();
            });
        }
    });

    function unloadIFrame(){        
        frame.src = "about:blank";
        updateStatus();
    }

    function updateStatus() {
        if(frame.src === "about:blank"){//empty iframe
            makePassive();
            status = 'pasif';
        } else {//iframe loaded a page
            makeActive();
            status = 'aktif';
        }
    }
    function makePassive() {
      $("#kapat").attr("data-status", "pasif");
      $("#kapat").css("background-color", "#ddd");
      $("#request").prop("disabled", true);
    }

    function makeActive() {
      $("#kapat").attr("data-status", "aktif");
      $("#kapat").css("background-color", "#000");
      $("#request").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is better but it's gave me a `error : jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function` for this $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#iframe").load(function() {
    aktiflestir();
  });

Comment: As mentioned in the answer above, `.load` is no longer a thing in jQuery 3.0 and higher. Instead use: `$(document).ready(function(e) { $("#iframe").on('load', function() { aktiflestir(); })`