# Load mysql query after pageload

Tags: javascript

I have a few queries that are quite big, i only want queries to run them once the page has finished loading.

This is what i have tried.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $("#query").load("sql-query.php");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div id="query">Loading...</div>
```

sql-query.php

```
$data = DB::table('tapplicant')->limit(5000)->get();
var_dump($data);
```

The idea is to return the query data once the page has loaded.

Comment: @Amani , im new to Javascript and Ajax, how would i do that or could you refer me to some documentation, thanks for the help

Comment: You can use `jQuery.ready()` instead of `.load()`

Comment: I re-built your case and I got this error : `TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function`   so your problem is the jquery version .. you can no longer use   `$(window).load(function() {});` use   `$(window).on("load", function (e) {})`  instead --> please see:https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version mismatch ["Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" error when opening new foundation project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat)

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        $( window ).load(function() {
          $("#query").load("sql-query.php");
        });         
        */
        $(window).on('load', function(){ 
            $("#query").load("sql-query.php");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div id="query">Loading...</div>
```

Suggest you to use document ready function (i.e `$(function()`) instead of window onload [document.ready vs window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions)

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#query").load("sql-query.php");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div id="query">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) after the [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $.get( "sql-query.php", function( data ) {
         $( "#query" ).html( data );
     });
 });
```

Comment: thank you, this work if i call a html file, but not php file

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some changes made in this JQuery version ..

Just change

`$(window).load(function() {});`
to

`$(window).on("load", function (e) {});` and keep the rest as it is.

Please refer to [this](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed) for more details.