# a.indexOf is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have an old site, so i update the jquery to the latest version, now i have a lot of errors in the console :
`a.indexOf is not a function` and `Query.Deferred exception: a.indexOf is not a function`.

I have search the net and found it maybe of this script that is deprecated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main2").load("newsong.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#main2").load('newsong.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 30000); //30 SEGUNDOS
 });
</script>
```

i try to change it like this but failed:

"replace them with .on() to register listeners instead. 
Example:

```
$(window).load(function(){...});
```

becomes:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){ ...});"
```

Comment: Why is `php` tag here?

Comment: make sure you did load the jQuery library

Comment: there isn't enough code here neither; post the html for this also

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i think it is loaded like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="/web/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: The change you applied makes no sense. Jquery [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) loads data for the server, while $(selector).on('load') would register a listener that would be invoked when the **load** event is triggered.

Comment: There are too many possible duplicates. Googling that error showed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat of many. Check your jQuery version also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" error when opening new foundation project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat)