# Retrieve xml data in table format in html

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, xml

I want to retrieve XML data in HTML in table format. I tried using ajax but data is not coming. Here what might be the issue can anyone help me out. I new to ajax. Feel free to tell anything wrong in my code. Below is the image I want to like this 
[image]

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $(window).load(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '2.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function myFunction(xml) {
       var i;
       var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
       var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
       var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
       for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
         table += "<tr><td>" +
         x[i].getElementsByTagName("Process")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td><td>" +
         x[i].getElementsByTagName("Product")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("Operation")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("Description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("QTY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("PlannedSchedule")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("ActualSchedule")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>" +
         x[i].getElementsByTagName("Status")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
         "</td></tr>";

       }
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
     }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="demo"></table>
```

XML:

```
  <Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
      <Row>
      <Process>70787863</Process>
      <Product>600033</Product>
      <Operation>Operation goes here</Operation>
      <Description>Operation description goes here</Description>
      <Batch>259</Batch>
      <QTY>999</QTY>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <Process>707863</Process>
      <Product>6033</Product>
      <Operation>Operation goes here</Operation>
      <Description>Operation description goes here</Description>
      <Batch>249</Batch>
      <QTY>99</QTY>
   </Row>
   </Rowset>
   </Rowsets>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think the problem with your code is you are getting undefined in xmlDoc..

**You can achieve it with the following code.**

> HTML

```
<table id="demo">
<thead>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Process</th>
    <th>Operation</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Batch</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
```

> JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.xml',//Your xml data
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find("Row").each(function(){
            var Product = $( this ).find( 'Process' ).text()
            var Process = $( this ).find( 'Product' ).text()
            var Operation = $( this ).find( 'Operation' ).text()
            var Description = $( this ).find( 'Description' ).text()
            var Batch = $( this ).find( 'Batch' ).text()
            var Qty = $( this ).find( 'Qty' ).text()
            $('#demo tbody').append('<tr><td>'+Product+'</td><td>'+Process+'</td><td>'+Operation+'</td><td>'+Description+'</td><td>'+Batch+'</td><td>'+Qty+'</td></tr>')

        });
    }
    })
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `e.indexOf` is not a function

Comment: The code is working fine at my end..Did u include the jquery and changed the url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat checkout the link for the error

Answer (score 0):

You should really look in to JQuery Datatables, I use them all the time to fill a table with Ajax data.

[JQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formatXml(xml) {
  var formatted = '';
  var reg = /(>)(<)(\/*)/g;
  xml = xml.replace(reg, '$1\r\n$2$3');
  var pad = 0;
  xml.split('\r\n').forEach(function (node) {
    var indent = 0;
    if (node.match(/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/)) {
      indent = 0;
    } else if (node.match(/^<\/\w/)) {
      if (pad !== 0) {
        pad -= 1;
      }
    } else if (node.match(/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/)) {
      indent = 1;
    } else {
      indent = 0;
    }

    var padding = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
      padding += '  ';
    }

    formatted += padding + node + '\r\n';
    pad += indent;
  });

  return formatted;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your AJAX request is successfully sent and you successfully receive the XML below as a response:

```
  <Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
      <Row>
      <Process>70787863</Process>
      <Product>600033</Product>
      <Operation>Operation goes here</Operation>
      <Description>Operation description goes here</Description>
      <Batch>259</Batch>
      <QTY>999</QTY>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <Process>707863</Process>
      <Product>6033</Product>
      <Operation>Operation goes here</Operation>
      <Description>Operation description goes here</Description>
      <Batch>249</Batch>
      <QTY>99</QTY>
   </Row>
   </Rowset>
   </Rowsets>
```

and you want to convert it into HTML. So, I will use this XML as my point of departure and convert it into proper HTML structure:

```js
let input = `
  <Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
      <Row>
      <Process>70787863</Process>
      <Product>600033</Product>
      <Operation>Operation goes here</Operation>
      <Description>Operation description goes here</Description>
      <Batch>259</Batch>
      <QTY>999</QTY>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <Process>707863</Process>
      <Product>6033</Product>
      <Operation>Operation goes here</Operation>
      <Description>Operation description goes here</Description>
      <Batch>249</Batch>
      <QTY>99</QTY>
   </Row>
   </Rowset>
   </Rowsets>
`;

let rows = input
    .replaceAll("<Rowsets>", "<table id='foo'>")
    .replaceAll("</Rowsets>", "</table>")
    .replaceAll("<Rowset>", "<tbody>")
    .replaceAll("</Rowset>", "</tbody>")
    .replaceAll("<Row>", "<tr>")
    .replaceAll("</Row>", "</tr>").split("\n");
let headers = [];
for (let index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
    if (rows[index].trim().indexOf("</") > 0) {
        let tmp = rows[index].substring(rows[index].indexOf("<") + 1);
        tmp = tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf(">"));
        if (headers.indexOf(`<th>${tmp}</th>`) < 0) headers.push(`<th>${tmp}</th>`);
        rows[index] = rows[index].replace(`<${tmp}>`, "<td>").replace(`</${tmp}>`, "</td>");
    }
}
rows[rows.map(item => item.trim()).indexOf("<tbody>")] = `<thead>${headers.join("")}</thead><tbody>`;
//console.log(rows);
document.write(rows.join("\n"));
```

Note that I assumed that the tags are in separate lines, just like in your example. The solution works if we can rely on this assumption.