# Rails 5 JQuery Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a JQuery error after deploying my app on Heroku

I use Rails 5.2. So this error prevents all the following js code to load.

Gemfile :

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min
//= require bootstrap
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//
```

I precompiled my assets before deploying to heroku with :

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The ERROR :

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.indexOf is not a function
```

I inspected the error, and it comes from this function :

```
/*!
 * Sizzle CSS Selector Engine v2.3.3
 * https://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2016-08-08
 */
```

Go to [deployed page on heroku](https://calm-depths-37631.herokuapp.com/login) and open up the console to see the error.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: @Loqman in the console. You can check it here : https://calm-depths-37631.herokuapp.com/login

Comment: As I can see. You are using Jquery "3.2.1" version. Can you try with lower version "2.1.0" or below? You can check something relevant on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat . Let me know if does not work.

Comment: This error might be caused by jQuery event aliases like `.load`, `.unload` or `.error` deprecated since jQuery 1.8 and removed in 3.0. As @Anshul suggested try using older version of jQuery and see if it works.

Comment: @Loqman It seems to work with JQuery2 ! `//= require jquery2` in my application.js

Comment: @LarryBird Since the comment worked for you, I have posted it as an answer. Please go ahead and accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might be caused by jQuery event aliases like `.load`, `.unload` or `.error` deprecated since jQuery `1.8` and removed in `3.0`.

Using lower versions like `2.1` will solve your problem.