# How to handle eventListener for iframe in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added the iframe code in the Html code which is the default iframe tag of the Dialogflow WebDemo. When you go through the picture which I have uploaded that indicates that when the user types the message and presses enter then automatically it display other response. What I need is when the user presses the enter then I should write the function in the script.

[image]

Here is the code of iframe tag in the HTML -

```
<iframe allow="microphone;" id="myFrame" width="350" height="430" src="dialogflow_bot_link"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("iframe").load(function(){
    $(this).contents().on("keyup", function(){
      // handle 'keyup' event
    });
  });
});
```

`iframe` tag embeds a separate webpage into the parent webpage. So we use [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the contents of the iframe and [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the immediate children within the iframe.

Comment: When I am trying to add the above piece of code I am getting this error "e.indexOf is not a function at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (VM2682 jquery.min.js:2)"

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252711/6513921). Most probably `load()` is deprecated in your version. Try replacing `load(function(){...})` with `.on('load', function(){ ...})`.

Comment: No, the error has rectified but it's not entering into the function $(document).ready(function(){
  $("iframe").on('load', function(){
    $(this).contents().on("keyup", function(){
      alert("Wow!")
    });
  });
});

Comment: Do we need to add any attribute in iframe tag

Comment: No additional options are needed. It means that the `.on('load',...)` may not be firing as expected.

Comment: Try passing the function to `$(window)` selector instead of `$(document)` selector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209557/discussion-between-sravya-gajavalli-and-michael-d).