# Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function while upgrading JQuery version

Tags: jquery, django

I got an error while upgrading `jQuery` version from 2.2.4 to 3.6.3 and `Bootstrap` from 3.3.6 to 3.3.7.

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            {% block meta %}
                <link rel="icon" href="{% static '/images/logo.jpg' %}">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            {% endblock meta %}
            <title>Page {% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
            {% block stylesheets %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "/login-assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}'>
                <!--Bootstrap-->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "/vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" %}'>
                <!-- Theme style -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "/login-assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.css" %}'>
                <!-- Custom Login style -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "/login-assets/dist/css/custom-login.css" %}'>
                <!-- Font Awesome -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}'>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome-animation.css" %}'>
                <link href='{% static "/vendors/sweetalert/css/sweetalert2.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
                <style>
                    body {
                        width: 100%;
                        min-height: 100%;
                        display: -webkit-box;
                        display: -webkit-flex;
                        display: -moz-box;
                        display: -ms-flexbox;
                        display: flex;
                        flex-wrap: wrap;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;
                        padding: 15px;
                        background-image: url("/static/images/login_background.jpg");


                }
                #particles-js{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: 50% 50%;
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0px;
                }
                .login-page{
                    margin-top: 10%;
                    width: 43%;
                    padding-top: 0%
                }
            </style>
        {% endblock stylesheets %}
    {% endblock head %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
        {% block content %}
            <!-- {{ content }} -->
        {% endblock content %}
        {% block js %}
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src='{% static "/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" %}'></script>
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <script src='{% static "/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}'></script>
            <!-- Sweet Alert2 -->
            <script src='{% static "/vendors/sweetalert/js/sweetalert2.min.js" %}'></script>
            <script src='{% static "/src/js/ajax-core.js" %}'></script>
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src='{% static "/build/js/particles-custom.js" %}'></script>
<!--                <script>-->
<!--                    $(document).ready(function() {-->
<!--                        $("body").prepend('<div id="particles-js"></div>');-->
<!--                    });-->
<!--                </script>-->
            <script src="/static/vendors/jsencrypt/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
        {% endblock js %}
    {% endblock body %}
</body>
```

When web page is loaded , it is taking too much time . Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Without seeing your code then we can't help you

Comment: Ok then , I will share the html code @ 
Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: code added@Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: Looks like you ran in the the issue answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252711/17839690