# jQuery: get image height, assign to image

Tags: jquery, html

This sounds simple enough, but so far I have been unable to solve it. I have a large number of images that for various reasons need to have their height explicitly defined. Assuming no two images have the same height, what would be the best way to find the height of each individual image within `div.column` and then assign the `height` as a parameter to the corresponding image?

**HTML**

```
<div class="column">
    <ul>    
        <li><img alt="Logo" src="images/logos1.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Logo" src="images/logos2.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Logo" src="images/logos3.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Logo" src="images/logos4.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Logo" src="images/logos5.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Logo" src="images/logos6.jpg /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <ul>    
        <li><img alt="Icon" src="images/icon1.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Icon" src="images/icon2.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Icon" src="images/icon3.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Icon" src="images/icon4.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Icon" src="images/icon5.jpg /></li>
        <li><img alt="Icon" src="images/icon6.jpg /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: will all the images have the same height? or will each have a different height?

Comment: do you know the image height for all images beforehand? is the height variable between different images?

Comment: The images all have varying heights and may be different each time you load the page.

Comment: you say 'that' height... what height?

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I just edited, hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: what are your css for those images? Logo and Icon?

Comment: `height` tag? I think you wanted to say parameter

Comment: Ok... readed again. You want that the image has: `style="height:NNpx"` ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: Yes, either `style="height:NNpx"` or `height = NNpx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best way to do it:

```
$('div.column img').each(function(){
    var image = $(this);
    var realHeight = image.attr("naturalHeight");
    image.attr('height', realHeight);
});
```

The trick is to access the `naturalHeight` property instead of access CSS rules.