# Getting original image for cropping, ignoring the width attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jcrop

My user can upload really big images, and for *cropping* and *display* purposes i'm adding `width` attribute so it will fit well in the browser window. Real image size can be - say 1920 x 1080 px.

```
<!-- width added for display purpose -->
<img class="croppable" src="images/fhd.jpg" width="640" />
```

In order to calculate **real selection box dimension** (if the `x` coordinate is 20px then would be 60px in the original full hd picture) i need to get the full image size **before** apply the `width` attribute.

The **problem** is that this will return 640 as value, taking into account the width attribute:

```
// Important: Use load event to avoid problems with webkit browser like safari
// when using cached images
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.croppable').each(function(){
        alert(this.width);
    });
});
```

**Please don't flag this as duplicate since what i'm asking is completly different from simple image width/height retrival (which works, actually).**

**EDIT**: Chris G. solution seems not working:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.croppable').each(function(){
        console.log(this.src);
        var original = new Image(this.src);
        console.log(original);
        $("#original_w").text(original.width); // Temp, more images to be added
        $("#original_h").text(original.height); // Temp, more images to be added
    });
});
```

Console output:

```
http://localhost/DigitLifeAdminExtension/images/pillars-of-creation.jpg
<img width="0">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the width/height of the image itself, not the div it is contained within.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.croppable').each(function(){
        var img = new Image();
        img.src =  $(this).src;
        alert(img.width);
    });
});
```

Comment: New object for getting width only, can this be overkill?

Comment: Most likely not. Test it with Firebug and benchmark to decide for yourself. Avoid over-engineering.

Comment: I updated my answer. You'll want it to wait until the document is finished loading.

Comment: What about webkit browsers like safari and cached images, look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: @Gremo you have to read the image width and height inside the onload handler. Like so: var img = new Image($(this).src); img.onload = function() { alert(img.width }; This has nothing to do with the document readiness.

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa i'm always getting 0 (zero).

Comment: @Gremo Can't use the Image() prototype like that. Easy to forget.

Comment: @ChrisG. thanks, now it's working fine. But i didn't tested in webkit chrome with cached images. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the attributes, get the width and put the attributes in place again:

```
var $img = $(img);
var oldWidth = $img.attr("width");
var imgWidth = $img.removeAttr("width").width();

$img.width(oldWidth);
```

But I think Chris G.'s answer works well too, just making sure it will be loaded when you try to get the width:

```
img.onload = function() {
    if (!img.complete) return; // IMG not loaded
    width = img.width;
   imgManipulationGoesHere();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in most up-to-date browsers and IE9.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.croppable').each(function(){
        alert(this.naturalHeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The working solution would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('img.croppable').each(function () {

        var original = new Image(this.src);
        original.onload = function () {
            alert(original.src + ': ' + original.width + 'x' +original.height);
        };
    });
});
```