# Getting image height after image has been resized using css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, image, resize

I am a bit stuck. I am creating a rotating background image with jquery and css. I resize the image width according to the browser size, but I do not want to change the height because it distorts the picture. So I want to do a simple math equation to make the image vertically centered on the screen. For example: The image has an original size of 1600px and it resizes to 1200px, I need to get the height of the resized image. I have tried this with jquery simple: $("#img1").height(); but it returns the value 0. Here is my jquery, html and css:

HTML

```
<div id="div2"><img src="images/1.jpg" class="bg" id="img1" /></div>
<div id="div3"><img src="images/1-blur.jpg" class="bg"/></div>
<div id="content">Body Content goes here!!</div>

<script>
var iheight = $("#img1").height();
$("#content").append(iheight);
</script>
```

CSS
    body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
    .bg {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #content{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    }

And Jquery to rotate images:

```
$(window).load(function(){
function startfade(){

$("#div3").fadeIn(3000, function(){
    $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    $("#div2").fadeIn(3000, function(){
        $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
});
});

}
setInterval(function() {
      startfade();
}, 6000);


startfade();


});
```

Any help on how to get the actual height of the image would be awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call height when image is loaded (and you should always enclose your code in `$(function() {});` so your code is invoked when DOM is ready)

```
$(function() {
   $('#img1').load(function() {
       $("#content").append($(this).height());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer of a similar thread I found on stackflow.. hope it helps !

```
var img = $("img")[0]; // Get my img elem
var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
$("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        pic_real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
    });
```

Comment: Link here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score 0):

I use this formula, getting the ratio height/width of the original image

```
var ratio=originalImageHeight/originalImageWidth;
var newHeight=newWidth * ratio;
```