# create canvas dynamically in wordpress and use original image size and position

Tags: wordpress, canvas

Okay, I am quite new to Javascript and JQuery, but after hours and hours of research I can't help myself but ask this question.

I want to write a hoverfunction that creates a greyscale-version of an image and lies this new black-and-white image above the original.
I've found a nice working code on spyrestudios.com, so my code looks like this:

HTML normal code

```
<!--IMG that is only an example with fixed sizes to make the script work.  -->
            <img id="canvasSource" class="testpic" width="480" height="321" alt="" src="canvas.jpg" title="bryom">

        <!--canvas that is only a dummy to test the script, later the canvas shouldn't be fixed in the html but created by jquery dynamically -->
        <canvas id="area" width="480" height="321" style="display:none"> </canvas>
```

and Script

```
    <!-- fill canvas with greyscale version -->
        var canvas = document.getElementById("area");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var image = document.getElementsByClassName("testpic");

        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 480, 321); <!--width and height are here only testnumbers because image size may change within the webpage, numbers should be replaced by variables if possible -->
        var pix = imgd.data;
        for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        var grayscale = pix[i  ] * .3 + pix[i+1] * .59 + pix[i+2] * .11;
        pix[i  ] = grayscale;   // red
        pix[i+1] = grayscale;   // green
        pix[i+2] = grayscale;   // blue
        // alpha
        }
        context.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
    };

<!-- Hover Image shows canvas with black and white -->  

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("img").mouseover(function(){
            $("canvas").css("display", "block");
            });

            $("img").mouseout(function(){
            $("canvas").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
```

so far, so good. All the tutorials and descriptions I found (and understood) had two problems:

1. I am working with wordpress, so I can't really add the canvas-container into the html-code myself. I have to create the canvas dynamically with jquery, dependent on how big the picture on the currentpage is and what kind of position it has inside its container.

2.nd problem is that they create the canvas in the normal flow, which means next to the original image. I would love the canvas to lie directly on the original image, but I have no idea how to read out size and position of the original image and use them for creating the canvas.

I guess this must be very easy, but I can't really focus out how exactly the things have to be connected in the code.
I have really no idea how to start with this and I couldn't find something as simple as I need it.

Except

```
var img = document.getElementByClassName("testpic");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

all the beginning is missing. How do I ask for the image size of any picture with the class "testpic"? How do I get the position? How do I use this creating the canvas in jquery?

I would be really thankful for help as this is my first trial to find help by a forum like this!! Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

To create the canvas, I recommend you to use this open source library http://georgealways.github.com/gee/

Getting the image resolution is a bit more complicated and depends on the browser. Discussed already on this page: [Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

My suggestion, however, is not to use the original image and not to put a canvas over it. That's just nonsense: try instead just using a single canvas that, on g.mouseover, makes your image b/n

First, put this code on the html page to create the canvas

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MYAPP.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="gee.js"></script> 

window.onload = function() {
var g = new GEE( { width: 600, height: 480 } );
document.body.appendChild( g.domElement );
MYAPP(g);
}
```

then, create the MYAPP.JS file and make it something like this

```
function MYAPP(g) {

// TODO:
// print out the image

g.mouseover = function() {

// TODO:
// clear screen and
// print out the b/n image

}}
```

Whenever working on the MYAPP.JS file, don't forget that to access the canvas and the context you'll have to do it this way

```
// Access the canvas (you'll probably don't need this)
g.domElement

// Access the context (you'll use this a lot)
g.ctx
```

Comment: if you found this useful, would you mind giving a "correct answer" tag? Thanks :)