# Find out what the width of an image is using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, width

I have these images that I am getting off my server and a database using PHP

```
<div class="pics">

<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" height="200"/>

</div>
```

There actual sizes are huge, but I need them to all be at a height at 200.

How do I find the width of this image using jQuery, I cant find a tutorial anywhere....

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for you're time,
J

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try `.innerWidth()` instead of `.width()`, as `.width()` would include the margin.

```
$('img').innerWidth();
```

If your image is really that big, you should consider scaling it down it server-side.

### Update

Actually `.width()` is not adding the margin and furthermore its not even adding the padding. That makes `.width()` more suitable than `.innerWidth()`. Thanks SKS.

Comment: `width() would include the margin` - Not true. `.width` will return just the elements width without `padding/border/margin`.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `.width` function. something like `$('img').width();`

More reading.. http://api.jquery.com/width/

Further more, there are `.innerWidth` and `.outerWidth` functions to include/exclude padding,border and margins. See below image for details,

[image]

Comment: Definitely reference what davidethell posted, because .height() and .width() will return 0 if the image has not finished loading when called. Using these methods will work but you need to make sure the image has finished loading.

Comment: @spoonybard896 `<img src="upload/<?php echo $array['image'] ?>" height="200"/>` doesn't look like he is loading dynamically.

Comment: True, but as I understand it, if the actual image content has not finished loading and you ask for it's width/height, you will get zero in Webkit browsers.

Comment: @spoonybard896 OP never mentioned where he is going to call `.width`. Even the one in the post will not work if it is not loaded. That post was talking about loading an image using `.load` and getting the width the image before inserting it in DOM. You CANNOT calculate width of something that is not loaded.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that when using .width and .height, making sure the image has loaded should be taken into account