# changing the css max-width of a collection textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a collection of textareas I am getting using a selector.  I am then iterating through and trying to set the max width for each based on its current width(they are not all the same, that is why I am doing it this way).  However, I can not access the .css property of the elements in the array, I guess because they are HTMLTextAreaElements?  Is there a way to make this work or a better way to approach this?

I can not set the max width statically because this is a generic control that is used in a variety of pages and with a variety of different sizes.

```
$(function () {
var a = $('.myTextAreaCssClass');
for(var i = 0;i < a.length; i++) {
var w = a[i].css(width);
a[i].css('max-width',w);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use $.each. Try this,

```
$(function () {
   var a = $('.myTextAreaCssClass');
   a.each (function () {
      $(this).css('max-width', $(this).css('width'));
   });
});
```

or you can make use of css function argument as given below,

```
$(function () {
   var a = $('.myTextAreaCssClass');
   a.css ('max-width', function () {
      return $(this).css('width');
   });
});
```

**Edit:**
I just realized this is really just setting the max width to the width I designated in my css file, what I need is the width in pixels – jas

Try this,

```
$(function () {
   var a = $('.myTextAreaCssClass');
   a.css ('max-width', function () {
      return $(this).width(); //returns computed width
   });
});
```

Note: there are different version of `width()` function so use accordingly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018686/297641

Comment: `.each()` is a much better option in this case.

Comment: thanks, I guess it was an issue because I used the javascript way instead of jquery?  Just out of curiosity, is it normal for the width() property in this case to be 0?

Comment: I just realized this is really just setting the max width to the width I designated in my css file, what I need is the width in pixels

Comment: @jas Try using `.width()` function. Something like `a.css ('max-width', function () { return $(this).width(); });`

Comment: I did that, but it returns 0? That's what I was trying to say in my comment above.

Comment: I can give it a shot, there's a lot going on but I'll try to isolate it down to a minimum viable example

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('.myTextAreaCssClass');

a.each(function() {
  w = $(this).width();
  $(this).css('max-width',w + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.myTextAreaCssClass').each(function(){
    $(this).css("max-width", $(this).css("width"))
})
```