# Getting parent <td> width from child's class name

Tags: jquery, html

Is there anyway to get the width of a  element using the class name of a child element?

```
 <td width='100%' nowrap='1' style='padding-left:2px; margin:2px;'>
     <font class='DialogHeaderTitleFont'>RudimentalDrumming.com Jackets</font>
 </td>
```

In the above code, I would like to get the width of the  element by using the class name of the  element, ".DialogHeaderTitleFont", is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Font tags are no longer in common use. Use a SPAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep just use .parent();

```
$(".DialogHeaderTitleFont").parent().css("width");
```

keep in mind if you repeat this class anywhere in your document variable may change, so I suggest you use some kind of unique identifier like an id and not a class

Comment: +1 for good answer (though I think `.closest` would be better). -1 for "suggest you use some kind of unique identifier like an id". Result - 0

Comment: using classes to get specific values is not the best practise I can assure you that, unless you actually write that class for jquery purposes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230636/css-optimization-element-id-vs-class?#answer-1230650

Comment: You're making an assumption that the class won't be used in multiple places for styling purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.width` function to get the width of an element.

```
$('.DialogHeaderTitleFont').parent().width();
```

jQuery offers different variation of `width` function such as `innerWidth`, `width` and `outerWidth`.. For more details check this [Find out what the width of an image is using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018669/find-out-what-the-width-of-an-image-is-using-jquery/10018686#10018686)

**Edited:** Missed that you want the width of the parent element.Thanks [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348190/getting-parent-td-width-from-childs-class-name/14348227#comment19946638_14348227)

Comment: *"using the class name of a **child** element"* may need to add `.closest` or `.parent` to that. font tags also don't generally have a width.

Comment: @Vega. I'm with KevinB. You should use `.closest` to accommodate for future changes, especially so given the OPs use of legacy elements. Won't be long before that gets wrapped with `<strong>` :)