# jQuery calculate img's real height / width values which coming from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am in a situation that; need to calculate image's original `width` and `heigth` values when one of them defined 0 on css. I can't change CSS with jQuery, need to solve like this:

[Here is example link.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/46/)

CSS:

```
img { width:0px; }​
```

jQuery:

```
var imgHeight = $('img').height();
alert(imgHeight);//which returning 0 ofcourse
```

I hope this is possible with less code, thanks,

Comment: First that came to a head. You can create DOM-element `img` set `display: none` and `src` of your image. After image loaded you can get it's real dimensions

Comment: thanks for advice but it must be done with this way,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var img = $("img")[0];
alert( img.naturalWidth + "x" + img.naturalHeight );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/50/

Comment: @barlasapaydin because they are properties of the image and not jQuery object

Comment: i can't get this work on my site, need to try harder, thanks.

Comment: if it works in the demo then it's your responsibility to implement it right

Comment: Never knew about `naturalWidth`/`naturalHeight`. Great way to do it. +1.

Comment: @Esailija i found these alternate way too http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/61/ but didnt work on my site either, i guess; i am dealing with different problem in that site, thanks anyways.

Comment: @RobinMaben ofcoure Robin, this was good answer and lightened me that i am having another problem.

Comment: i coudn't worked your solution on my site but this way worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: You werent calling this after the image was loaded? I thought that was a given...

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $('img'),
    imgHeight = img.css("width","auto").height();
img.css("width","0");
alert(imgHeight);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/mjaA3/47/) is a fiddle. All we do is temporarily set the height to it's automatic value (which is the image's 100% width), grab the height, and reset the image to `width:0;`.

**EDIT:** Since you can't manipulate CSS directly, you can change the class:

```
var img = $('img'),
    imgHeight = img.addClass("auto").height();
img.removeClass("auto");
alert(imgHeight);​
```

And the CSS:

```
img {width:0;}
img.auto {width:auto;}​
```

Comment: thanks for answer but cant manipulate css from jQuery, need to solve with this way.

Comment: Then there's no other way, sorry. Can you manipulate classes?

Comment: yeah, i just cant change width here.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the element to a new hidden DOM node (I assume you want to hide it here). Then remove the CSS, then measure the dimensions.