# jQuery: how to access outside variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, undefined, local-variables

I am in a situation that needs be solve with this way; need convert a `local variable` to a `global variable`. There is an example returning image's real width and height which i found these method from [**this answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670433/1428241).

Need to convert local varialbes `pic_real_height` and `pic_real_width` to global variables with returning their true values.

**[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/78/)**

CSS :

```
img { width:0px; height:0px; }​
```

jQuery :

```
console.log($('.imgCon img').height());//returns 0

var img = $('.imgCon img')[0]; // Get my img elem
var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
$('<img/>').attr('src', $(img).attr('src')).load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   
        pic_real_height = this.height;

        console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );
        // -- returns true 570x320 --
});
//problem starts here:
console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );
//returns undefined
// need to return this as an global variable 570x320
```

Comment: They are already global, but the load happens asynchronous. Just move the alert in the callback function

Comment: Please learn to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, mainly by testing in Chrome, Firefox (with Firebug), or IE9.

Comment: As @Bergi said as well, a *callback* is called by `$.load()` (see the `function` part?) in which it's called, and literally this occurs *later on*. You need to learn how callbacks work.

Comment: @Bergi need to call them from outside of callback function /:

Comment: You can call them outside the callback function. Your problem is that `.load()` does not stop executing js code. so if you want to do anything with those variables you must wait until they are set by the callback function.

Comment: You don't explain what you really want to do with these variables, you are just `alert`ing them, so we cannot really suggest what you should be doing.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks for notice, i updated my question with console.log.

Comment: That's a minor (but *useful* for you) improvement. You really need to learn about callbacks and how they work. But the name, they *wait*. For...?

Comment: @Bergi please submit your answer as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: The title of the question should be edited. Can somebody, good with words, do that ?

Comment: @dsh: I don't think it is long enough to be an answer (and also has just earned me a badge :-). I'd rather close the question as a duplicate, but I fear there is still no answer-to-all-async-stuff question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line,

`console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );`

does not wait for these lines

```
    pic_real_width = this.width;   
    pic_real_height = this.height;

    console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );
    // -- returns true 570x320 --
```

to execute, because its asynchronous.

Thus,
 `console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );` executes before callback function gets called (i.e. before you set the `width` and `height` ).

Since, you havent defined them already, they show `undefined`.

A trivial solution would be,

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', $(img).attr('src')).load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   
        pic_real_height = this.height;

        console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );
        // -- returns true 570x320 --
        restOfMyProcessing();

}); 

function restOfMyProcessing() {
    console.log( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );
}
```

Comment: You're welcome but please do read about the asynchronous nature of js and the callbacks associated with that. One day, you will be doing ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use pic_real_width and pic_real_height before they set in image load event.
Like in your code, first `alert( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height )` is the one after image load function which returns `undefined` and the second `alert` in load event returns what you expect.
Although it's better to move setting of source attribute after load function/event:

```
$('<img/>')
.load(function() {
    pic_real_width = this.width;
    pic_real_height = this.height;

    alert( pic_real_width + 'x' + pic_real_height );
    // -- returns true 570x320 --
    //now continue process here or call another function...
})
.attr('src', $(img).attr('src'));
```