# How to function fire up from two different element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have an action start element `.oven_program_01`, panel with class `.oven_panel` started after click at this element.

I have another element `.back_button` which closes this panel.

When I open the panel again I can't close it. The display does't change.

This is my script:

opening action:

```
$('.oven_program_01').live('click', function() {
    $('.back_button').addClass('oven_panel_close_button');
    $('.oven_panel').fadeIn(300);
});​
```

closing action:

```
$('.back_button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("oven_panel_close_button")) {
        $('.oven_panel').fadeOut(300);
        $('.back_button').removeClass("oven_panel_close_button")
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("oven_panel_close_button")
    }
});​
```

Comment: Is the `.back_button` element dynamically added to the page? If so, you need to create a listener for that element; i.e. `$.on()`. In addition, the `$.live()` function has been depreciated. I suggest using `$.on()`.

Comment: no, this element is stage, so i need to do smth like that ?$('.back_button').on('click', function() {

Comment: This element is **stage**? Do you mean that this element is **static**?

Comment: yeap, sorry 4 mistake :)

Comment: The `$.on()` functions works 2 ways based on the parameters that you give it. `$('.back_button').on('click', function() { ...})` assumes that it is on the page all the time. But if the element is dynamic then you need to setup the `$.on()` function differently; `$("**body**").on("click", "**.back_button**", function() { ...})` where `$(ParentElement).on("click", ChildElement, function(){})` [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Yes. I would use the `$.on()` function. As @David said, make a Fiddle so that we can help further.

Comment: so this is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J5ane/ and it's work, but it's one radical diferent .oven_program_01 are dinamicly creating from xml, and have numbers from 01-09, thats why i use live, i i guess that's why this script does't work :(

Comment: this question migth help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811980/jquery-how-to-convert-local-variable-to-a-global-variable