# Access a local function outside the scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access a function declared in $(document).ready event outside of its scope?
In other words, how can I change a local function to global?

Comment: That's what scope means: the places where your function is known. So you can't.

Comment: this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811980/jquery-how-to-convert-local-variable-to-a-global-variable

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare the variable outside the scope and assign it inside the document ready method. Then you will be able to access it outside the document ready scope?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your function to window object in document `ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     window.YourFunc = function (){
     // Do something.
     };
});
```

And then call it whenever you want:

```
window.YourFunc();
```

But the best way is just define your function outside of `ready` handler.