# How do i get the image dimensions (height, width) from a file by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am probably being very very stupid. But i cant get this to work for my life. 
I am trying to set the `imgWidth` to the same width as the image width of the file (pic_real_width).

```
function calculate() {
    var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
    $("<img/>").attr("src", $("#pp_photo_popUp")[0].src).load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        pic_real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
    });
    var imgWidth = 
}
```

All in all I am trying to make a function to get the real dimensions of a file on the hard disk.

Comment: This isn't a scope issue, it's a timing issue. `var imageWidth =` is happening before `pic_real_width = this.width`

Comment: `load` calls `ajax`, which is asynchronous. Anything you want to do with the loaded image must be done in the callback.

Comment: @roasted it uses the onload event not ajax, but it is async (unless cached)

Comment: The better solution is to preload your images

Comment: @KevinB thx misread code btw thats why i always use .on('load',callback) ...

Comment: use an image onload callback

Comment: @dandavis He is using an image onload callback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value of JQuery ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768991/return-value-of-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: how can onload be defined after setting the src?

Comment: @dandavis as long as the image isn't cached, it would work.

Comment: @dandavis if you mean he should set handler before setting source, you are correct, he should

Comment: ?@KevinB: i disagree. if the same code doesn't do the same thing each time, it's busted.

Comment: @dandavis i have to be agree with you here

Comment: Isn't this awfully similar to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811980/jquery-how-to-access-outside-variable)?

Comment: @dandavis What's busted?

Comment: @Ian the fact that it works inconsistently, can be considered broken, or, *"busted"*. I'd just call it inconsistent.

Comment: @KevinB I agree on calling it "inconsistent". I just don't see how it's relevant - there are **many** things that are inconsistent...but there are ways to make things work "consistently"...and in this case, that would be setting the `src` *after* the event binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the load event First, and then do all processing that needs the image to be loaded inside of the load event.

```
function calculate(callback) {
    $("<img/>").load(function() {
        var pic_real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        var pic_real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
        callback(pic_real_width,pic_real_height);
    }).attr("src", $("#pp_photo_popUp")[0].src);
}

calculate(function(width,height) {
    console.log(width,height);
});
```

If you set the src first, some versions of IE will immediately trigger the load event synchronously, thus triggering it before you have even bound to it. That's why i swapped the order. Additionally, I added the callback parameter because I assume later in the function you were going to return the width/height, which won't work due to the asynchronous nature of load events.

Comment: Are you sure it's only "some versions of IE"? I think it's all browsers...if the image is cached, the `load` event fires immediately when setting the `src`. I've never really had to test this (especially in all browsers) though

Comment: It may be all versions of IE, but some browsers do actually trigger the event asynchronously when it is cached, meaning binding the event after setting the src will work in those browsers even on cached images. I'm not sure about current versions of the browsers, all the testing i did on this was ~ a year ago and IE was the only browser that triggered it synchronously.

Comment: @KevinB kinda saved my day, thanks, I should have thought of this being an asynchronous function. How process intensive is this though? I mean if I were to call this every time when a user switches to the next photo, would that be fine?