# Return a variable from a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the value of `imgWidth`? This is giving me `undefined`.

```
somejQueryMethod(function() { 
    var imgWidth;
    $("<img/>").attr(
        "src", 
        $("#SomeImgSelector").attr("src")
    ).load(function() {
        imgWidth = this.width;
    });
    // use imgWidth here
    // imgWidth is undefined here
});
```

> **Background info**: From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670433/31399) I assumed that as `imgWidth` was being defined outside of the `load()` method,
>   it would always be available outside of `load()`. Which makes me
>   wonder why define `imageWidth` there and not in `load()`?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the `undefined` error?

Comment: You have to wait until the `$.load()` callback runs, which means you need the callback to use `imgWidth` (basically, where you've set the variable). `$.load()` is asynchronous, which means it allows the code to continue while it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the value there, because it doesn't exist yet. The callback function in the `load` command runs after the content has been loaded, and that happens after the function using the `load` command ends.

Put the code that needs the value inside the callback function for the `load` command:

```
...somejQueryMethod(
    function() { 
        var imgWidth;
        $("<img/>").attr("src", $("#SomeImgSelector").attr("src")).load( function() {
          imgWidth = this.width;
          // use imgWidth here
        } );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You cannot use it there as it doesn't have a value yet - you should use it within or after the load handler function when it has been defined.

Edit: just to add, take a moment to think what you're doing there. When you're changing the src attribute, you're telling it to load an image from some url. Then, you're attaching a load event to trigger (when it has done loading) to capture the width of the loaded image. Now, of course you cannot use that value until the code has done loading the image. Here you're using asynchronous loading, which in practice means that your code will be processed to the end and loading will happen "in the meantime", so it will not wait for that loading of image to complete. If you want to, you could also change your code so that it will actually wait for it to complete, or you can play around with the width in the load handler, as others have demonstrated.

Comment: `imgWidth` _is_ defined there, it just has a value of `undefined`. So yes, it should be used within the load handler or in some other function called from within the load handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn right. I fixed that. It is defined, but it doesn't have a value yet (beyond undefined).

Answer (score 3):

The `load` function is **asynchronous**, which means that you will need to provide all the functionality within the callback function.

```
somejQueryMethod(function() {         
    $("<img/>").attr(
        "src", 
        $("#SomeImgSelector").attr("src")
    ).load(function() {
        var imgWidth = this.width;
        // use imgWidth here
    });
});
```