# Removing small images

Tags: jquery

I have following script to remove images that are too small but it doesn't work properly, first time I load the page, every image gets replaced with `no-image.png`, after I refresh page it works properly, what am I missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.story-img').error(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/Images/no-image.png");
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
    });

    $(".story-img").each(function () {

        var theImage = new Image();
        theImage.src = $(this).attr("src") || $(this).src;

        var imageWidth = theImage.width;
        var imageHeight = theImage.height;

        if (imageWidth < 32 || imageHeight < 32 || $(this).height() < 32 || $(this).width < 32) {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Images/no-image.png");
            $(this).css('border', 'none');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know what values `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` have? I guess it's because the images are not loaded yet and therefore have a width and height of 0. You could try replacing `.each` with `.load`. BTW: the line ending in `|| $(this).src;` should be `|| this.src;`

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the tips, I will try to make changes and see if it helps.

Comment: If the problem is still there after the changes, make a fiddle for us to play around with.

Comment: Or you can specify the image widths and heights with something like `<img src="path/to/image.png" width="200" height="200" />`

Comment: Better than a fiddle would be a link to the actual website.

Comment: @irrelephant thats why I am replacing Images, it looks ugly when you streach icon of 32x32 to 200x200

Comment: @Thomas It's not in production

Comment: @Thomas Would it make more sense to attach .load handler to theImage object, if that is even possible?

Comment: The 200s are just an example; you should replace them with the actual values. Or are you saying that you don't know the dimensions beforehand?

Comment: By the way, you can use `.load` as @Thomas suggested - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: @irrelephant That solved it, replacing `.each` with `.load`, I just have to check for any browser quirks. Thanks guyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably checking the with of the images before they're loaded (which makes their width and height equal 0). You can use `$(image).load()`:

```
$(".story-img").load(function () {

    //...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the image data hasn't finished loading before the page html is finished loading. You could use the javascript LOAD event, which waits until all images are finished loading. Use

```
$(window).load(function(){}
```