# get image size in page load with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to get and change size of images load in my DOM, but parent element .ui-page is in display:none; after the pageinit. I'm using [jqm pagination](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/) but I think I don't know something in jQuery Mobile to do it right.

Comment: I fix it by adding attribute width and height in html, but if you have another solution.

Comment: I find this usefull answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome#3192577