# jQuery getting image width/height loaded within a container

Tags: jquery, css, image

I'm working with a plugin that requires me to get the width and height of the image, after it's loaded, regardless of how the dimensions of the image were determined.

```
<img src=".." width="500" height="500" />                <!-- works fine -->
<img src=".." style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" />    <!-- works fine -->
<img src=".." width="500" />                             <!-- only gives me width -->
<img src=".." style="width: 500px;" />                   <!-- only gives me width -->
<img src=".." style="width: 500px; height: auto;" />     <!-- only gives me width -->
<img src=".." />                                         <!-- doesn't work at all -->
```

I have tried loading the image and getting its dimensions after but i've only been able to get the image's actual size and not the size at which it is display on the page.

The code im using to get the width/height:

```
img.innerWidth();
```

I Have also tried:

```
$('<img/>').hide().attr('src',img.src).load(function() {
    img.Owidth = $(this).width();
    img.Oheight = $(this).height();
}).appendTo($('body'));
```

And:

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", img.attr("src")).load(function() {
   img.width = this.width;
   img.height = this.height;
});
```

Which do a fine job at getting me the original size of the image, but not the size of when it's loaded and displayed.

Comment: The plugin or your code must be grabbing the width attribute, rather than finding the width of the element.

Comment: What code are you using to get the width and height?

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

Comment: Is there a particular plugin you are using to load the images?  A fiddle may also be helpful

Comment: @MikeB, I'm not using a particular plugin to load the images, but rather that im working on making a plugin that requires me to get the dispay width and height of the images. I'll get to work on a fiddle.

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/hxGPd/) for me in IE and Chrome (latest version) http://jsfiddle.net/hxGPd/ What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

```
img.clone().load(function() {
    img.Dwidth = $(this).width();
    img.Dheight = $(this).height();
}).appendTo(img.parent()).hide();
```

To get the display dimensions, in my particular case, I had to clone the element, reload it and get the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery `width` or `height` to get calculated and also if the item is visible you always get 0. if you update the code like below it should work.

```
$('<img/>').attr('src',img.src).load(function() {
    img.Owidth = $(this).width();
    img.Oheight = $(this).height();
}).appendTo($('body')).hide();
```

as you can understand, if you have used $(this).width() instead of this.width in second block it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case and it doesnt work. Also, this gives me the original image dimensions and not those of an image displayed within a container or that only has a width value defined, for example.

Comment: what do you mean by "when it's loaded and displayed.". This function should give dimension of the image but if you have another element which displays the image different width or height (by attr or CSS) you should use $().width() on that object.

Comment: http://joeyvo.me/lensview/ I added your code and all though it seems to be working fine in the fiddle, it isn't doing it in my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the size from the image, when you load your script with the $(window).load function.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    console.log($('img').width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getheight = function () {
var img = document.getElementById("pic");
var img_width = img.clientWidth;
}
```

Call this function after the image gets loaded . The clientWidth attribute will give you the image size after it gets loaded