# Callback after updating a view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learn AngularJS, and I created a little web app in order to exercise myself. It's a "chat", so the user write a message which is stored in a message array in the `$scope`. Now I would like to move the scrollbar to the bottom when a message is displayed to the view (`<p ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message.user}}: {{message.text}}`). So I've done something like :

```
$scope.messages.push(obj);
$("#messages").prop({scrollTop: $("#messages").prop("scrollHeight")}); // jQuery method, is there something like that in AngularJS ?
```

But, it doesn't work. The jQuery method itself works, but I think that at the moment it is invoked, the wiew hasn't been updated (is that right ?). **What can I do so that the method is called every update of this view ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently asked a similar question and the accepted answer solved my issue: [How to call a function when Angular is done updating the layout because of data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183049/how-to-call-a-function-when-angular-is-done-updating-the-layout-because-of-data)

Basically, I wrap the function to be called in another function. The outer function checks $scope.$$phase . If it is still apply or digest, I use $timeout to reinvoke the outer function in 100 ms. If not, then I call the function.