# Is it a good practice to use $scope.$apply() frequently?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was having problem when updating my list to **ng-repeat** in **view** and $scope.$apply came to the rescue. I am concerned about the watchers. Is it a good practice to use $scope.$apply() frequently? Since I am having many views in application which must be updated immediately on button click.
PS: Any alternatives are appreciated.
Sample JS code of my application:

```
function onRefreshList() {
    vm.showLoader = true;
    GetDataService.getVotes(someParams).then(function(res) {
    if (res){
        vm.showLoader = false;
        vm.voteList = res; //voteList will be updated on click of Refresh list 
        $scope.$apply(); //working fine with this }
    }).catch(function (res) {
        vm.showLoader = false;
        console.log("There was an error will loading votes");
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="showLoader">
    <ion-spinner icon="android" class="spinner-assertive"></ion-spinner>
</div>

<div ng-show="!showLoader" ng-repeat="vote in votesCtrl.voteList">
    {{vote}}
</div>
```

Comment: None of the hundreds of "when to use ... ?", "best practice using ... ", "when should I use ... ?" results on your preferred search engine helped?

Comment: Should only need to use it when code that updates scope is outside of angular context. Assuming `GetDataService.getVotes()` uses a third party javascript api you might want to look into returning `$q` promises instead. They are set up to not need `$apply()` as they call it internally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it safe to use $scope.$apply()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817111/when-is-it-safe-to-use-scope-apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS by default provides its own wrappers for JavaScript async:

1. Directives like `ng-click` or `ng-keydown`
2. `$http` service for asynchronous AJAX calls
3. `$timeout` and `$interval`

In my opinion, it is a bad practice to use `$scope.$apply()` method on your own and this method shouldn't be used randomly throughout your code. If it has to, it means you did something wrong when you thought about your app/module/component.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817111/when-is-it-safe-to-use-scope-apply).