# AngularJS OneTime Binding with ng-repeat doesn't let me refresh scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list that I am using `ng-repeat` and one-time binding because there is no need for me to update once I have the data.

I was hoping that I could use one-time binding and force a digest, but I get the common error that a `$digest is already being processed` or whatever it is.

My code looks like the following

```
$scope.$on(IonicEvents.beforeEnter, function() {
    Locations.getAllLocations()
        .then(function(allLocations) {
            $scope.model.locations = allLocations;
            //I have tried $scope.$digest()..
            //also $scope.$apply()...
        }, function(error) {
            $log.error('Error retrieving locations');
        })
});
```

My `ng-repeat` in my template looks like the following:

```
<ion-item class="item" ng-repeat="location in ::model.locations">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p>{{::location.name}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Any ideas, or am I completely off-track?

Answer (score 0):

I think First you may check if(!$scope.$$phase) then apply your proccess

```
$scope.$on(IonicEvents.beforeEnter, function() {
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    Locations.getAllLocations()
        .then(function(allLocations) {
            $scope.model.locations = allLocations;
            //I have tried $scope.$digest()..
            //also $scope.$apply()...

        }, function(error) {
            $log.error('Error retrieving locations');
        })
   }
});
```

Comment: no need to check for $scope.$$phase.  Its for angularjs internal use only. And it will not be supported in future.

Comment: you mean new version skip this step ??

Comment: Please check this link.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263118/what-is-phase-in-angularjs)

Comment: you see here also mentioned same problem ... $digest is already being processed

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you are off-track.

My idea for your particular situation would be using a clone object (with no reference to the main object) once they are retrieved from `Locations.getAllLocations()` using

```
$scope.clonedLocationObj = angular.copy($scope.model.locations);
```

and render this object to your view so that it won't effect your main object.

As far as one way binding is concerned, Angular doesn't let you change the one time binded model again because when we declare a value such as {{ ::foo }} inside the DOM, once this `foo` value becomes defined, Angular will render it, unbind it from the watchers and thus reduce the volume of bindings inside the $digest loop. Simple!
[angular one time binding syntax article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/)

Hope it helps.