# Trigger change programmatically : AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have this piece of code

```
<select id="headers" ng-model="importHeader.systemHeaders">
<option ng-repeat="requiredHeaders in vCtrl.wizard.costs.headerData.headers" value="{{requiredHeaders}}"  ng-selected="vCtrl.wizard.costs.changed(importHeader.headerName,requiredHeaders.displayName)">{{requiredHeaders.displayName}}
</option>
</select>
```

All i'm doing is looping through a set of headers and checks if the value of the imported Header is the same on what if required and it automatically selects it. It works fine, But my problem is that it won't add the `systemHeaders` in my `importHeaders` object declared on the `ng-model`

I need a way to trigger the change event of this `select`. I know that when changing the seletion programmatically it won't trigger the `ngChange` event.

i tried creating a function:

```
changed: function(val1,val2){
        if (val1 == val2){
            angular.element('#headers').change();
                return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

}
```

but it gets me an $apply is already in progress error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you assign this function with `$scope`?

Comment: No, i'm using `vm` when creating functions not `$scope`

Comment: Kindly post your full code

Comment: Which line threw this error?

Comment: `angular.element('#headers').change();` threw the $apply is already in progres error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this condition before change the header line

```
if($scope.$$phase)
{
angular.element('#headers').change();
}
```

And read this discussions : [What is $$phase in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263118/what-is-phase-in-angularjs)

Comment: gives me a never ending error on console which mainly says `digest already in progress`

Comment: oops. Just remove the line `$scope.$apply();
`