# How to get jQuery to wait for a list of images to load before processing them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How to tell jQuery to wait for a list of images to be loaded before starting an image carousel?

I have a list of large images that are to be used in an image carousel. These images are of different sizes and I want to use javascript/jQuery to size the viewport according to the widest image and at the same time scale all images to the same height.

```
<div id="viewport" style="overflow:hidden" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="carousel" style="width:2000em">
       <li><img src="large01.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="large02.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="large03.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="large04.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="large05.jpg"></li>
       <!-- li { float: left } -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I think I need to wait for all the images to load before I can determine their `$(img).height()` and `$(img).width()` but I have tried `$(document).ready()`, `$(window).load()`, `$(window).ready()` with inconsistent results across browsers. Furthermore, it seems that some `.load()` is deprecated already.

What is the correct method of dealing with this.

Or is there anyway to get the image width and height BEFORE the image is loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/javascript - Get Image size before load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850867/jquery-javascript-get-image-size-before-load)

Comment: `$('img').load(function() { console.log($(this).width()); })`?

Comment: @putvande See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ (the section that says `load` with images)

Comment: To those who voted to close, are you sure the answer on the other post is valid?

Comment: Even [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin?rq=1) fails to address cross browser issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
var images = $('#carousel img');
var count = images.length;
var loaded = 0;

images.each(function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        loaded += 1;

        if (loaded == count) {
            //all images loaded
        }
    }

    image.src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Comment: Somewhere on the internet says onload does not fire for images that are already cached...

Comment: @Jake you've been misinformed. This question is discussed here http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called

Comment: Argh... I see, you are "reloading" the images into a new Image().

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery documentation (see [jQuery .ready() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)), the correct way of waiting a page to load is '$( document ).ready( handler )'.
But to your question I would check the javascript naturalHeight property of the images (or naturalWidth if you will). I believe it's already set when the page is loaded (as per .ready function).
You should get the values you need to be able to scale your images.

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` does not wait for images to load before firing. '$(window).load()` does wait, but not consistent across browsers.