# How to make a background of unknown size to an HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, image

I want users to upload an image or specify a URL of an image and then be able to look like they're drawing on top of the image. So I can make a `<canvas>` element with a background image. But I don't know beforehand how big that image is (well I can figure it out if they uploaded an image). How can I deal with this using jQuery?

I know I can call `$('img#id_name').width` and create a canvas based on that width (and get the height the same way). But I want that to be the background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can get image's original width/height values after loading and than use `css()` method for defining values.

```
var img = $('img#id_name')[0]; // Get my img elem
var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
$("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        iWidth = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        iHeight = this.height; // work for in memory images.

   $('#canvasEle').css({'width': iWidth + 'px', 'height': iHeight + 'px'});
});
```

[Calculating image source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670433/1428241)

Comment: Note that this code should go into the onload event handler for the image, because you don't know the size until the image has loaded.

Comment: This code looks right, except that I wanted the size of the background image: `<div style="background-image: url(/images/bg.jpg);"></div>`