# Finding Image width and height by given maximum width and height with aspectratio

Tags: javascript, css, image, mozilla, aspect-ratio

I am trying to find the image aspectratio,so `width/height` gives the aspect ratio of any image. But i want to set the image width and height like mozilla sets width and height of an image when i set `max-width` or `max-height` to `somevalue`.

How to do this calculation to find width and height of an image with correct aspect ratio?

```
new_width = width/height*user_definedwidth;
```

like this, but i want to calculate both width and height for any image?

```
How mozilla sets both width and height with aspect ratio when max-width or max-height have set.
```

I need to show any user uploaded image with correct aspect ratio but large size images need to be resized.

```html
<img src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy-images.jpg" style='max-width:200px;'/>
```

Comment: This question might be helpful to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome