# Chrome not detecting image sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to make sure images larger then their viewing width will be opened in my image viewer. However on a 720p resolution, and Google Chrome, I get 0 for the width for both the original, and viewport widths...

Here is an example page where a image should be opened in BFX View (try in Chrome on lower resolution): [Live Example](http://www.beeskneesfx.com/showthread.php/497-Captian-America-Civil-War-poster)

**Log** (first image scanned is the image in question)

```
 Starting BFX View Version 0.3 Build 61 alpha
bfxcore.js:92 BFX View -> Looking for images in: .postpreview...
bfxcore.js:92 BFX View -> Looking for images in: .content...
bfxcore.js:109 Image: http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/originals/ed/e1/c7/ede1c78fe16fba4afd1606772a5fc1ac.jpg Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/smilies/wink.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/smilies/smile.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/primus/blue/misc/quote_icon.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/primus/blue/buttons/viewpost-right.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/smilies/wink.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/smilies/smile.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/primus/blue/misc/quote_icon.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
bfxcore.js:109 Image: images/primus/blue/buttons/viewpost-right.png Original Width: 0 Against: 0
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){

    /****************************************************
    /    BFX View version 0.3 build 56
    /    by WASasquatch for BeeskneesFX.com
    /***************************************************/

    // Global vars
    var appname = 'BFX View',
        appflag = 'alpha',
        appversion = 0.3,
        appbuild = 61,
    // Selectors
        findImagesIn = new Array(
                    '.postpreview',
                    '.content',
                    '.restore',
                    '.postbody'
                    ), // Master container class/id - all image tags in children elements get selected
    // Theater selectors
        theater = $('#theater-box'),
        theaterimg = theater.find('#theater-img'),
        theaterclose = theater.find('#theater-header span');        

    console.log('Starting '+appname+' Version '+appversion+' Build '+appbuild+' '+appflag);
    if ( notMobile === false ) {
        console.log(appname+' detected a mobile device. Disabling BFX View for performance. Visit us on a desktop!');
    } else {
        // Start a BFX View selector
        for (i=0; i<findImagesIn.length; i++) {
            console.log(appname+' -> Looking for images in: '+findImagesIn[i]+'...');
            $(findImagesIn[i]).each(function(){
                bfxView('.'+$(this).attr('class'));
            });
        }
    }

    function bfxView(id) {
        var imgCount = 0;
        $(id).each(function(){ 
            $(this).find('img').each(function () {
                var img = $(this),
                    width, height, origWidth = $(this).width();
                    hiddenImg = img.clone().attr('class','').attr('id','').css('visibility', 'hidden').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width').appendTo('#loading-images');
                height = hiddenImg.height();
                width = hiddenImg.width();
                hiddenImg.remove();
                console.log('Image: '+$(this).attr('src')+' Original Width: '+origWidth+' Against: '+width);
                if ( width > origWidth ) {
                    imgCount++;
                    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    var parent = $(this).parent();
                    if ( parent.attr('href') == $(this).attr('src') ) {
                        parent.attr('target','_self');
                        parent.removeAttr('href');
                    }
                    $(this).click(function () {
                        var startingPoint = $(document).scrollTop(),
                            theaterActive = true,
                            bodyo = $('body').css('overflow');
                            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                        theaterimg.html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" alt="Medium View" />');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            theaterimg.find('img').each(function(){
                                var renderWidth = $(this).width();
                                if ( renderWidth < width ) {
                                    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                                    theater.find('#viewfull').attr('href', '/viewer.html?src='+Base64.encode($(this).attr('src'))+'&t='+Base64.encode(window.location.href));
                                    theater.on('click', '#theater-img img', function(){
                                        window.location.href = '/viewer.html?src='+Base64.encode($(this).attr('src'))+'&t='+Base64.encode(window.location.href);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    theater.find('#viewfull').remove();
                                    $(this).attr('alt','Full Resolution View');
                                }
                            });
                        },0);
                        theater.fadeIn(1000, function () {
                            theaterclose.click(function () {
                                theater.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                                    theaterActive = false;
                                });
                                $('body').css('overflow', bodyo);
                            });
                        }); 

                    });

                }

            });

        });

        console.log(appname+' -> '+imgCount+' images found in '+id);

    }


});
```

I changed the code for searches intending to make sure all possible classes were checked. The old code for starting a search was

```
        for (i=0; i<findImagesIn.length; i++) {
            console.log(appname+' -> Looking for images in: '+findImagesIn[i]+'...');
            bfxView(findImagesIn[i]);
        }
```

**Updated Code** Still no go on Chrome and broken on Firefox with this edit. This will tell me "Width" and "height" is not defined, like no image is loaded.

```
            $(this).find('img').each(function () {
                $(this).load(function(){
                    var img = $(this),
                        width, height, origWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
                        hiddenImg = img.clone().attr('class','').attr('id','').css('visibility', 'hidden').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width').appendTo('#loading-images');
                    height = hiddenImg.height();
                    width = hiddenImg.width();
                    hiddenImg.remove();
                });
```

Comment: Chrome*** not Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example does not work:

```
BFX View -> 0 images found in ...
```

Anyway, you are trying to read the width before the image is loaded. Have a look at the answer for this question which actually covers the same topic:

[Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

For huge images i'd recommend to use a server side script that reads the image dimensions, so the client does not have to wait for the loading of all images to fire your script.

Comment: Server side is not a option. And most images are constrained if no link is given in bbcode and unclickable to begin with. So this is just a additional feature that would otherwise be a stale image. When it works, and it works in firefox just fine, there is really now lag when the images are loaded.

Comment: @WASasquatch The answer he linked to works perfectly. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add an event listener to all images and get their bounds after they are loaded >> for ex.

```
img.onload = function () {
    // get width and height of the img refering to it using "this" keyword
}
```

and if you are using JQuery

```
$(imgSelector).load(function(){
     // get width and height of the img refering to it using "$(this)"
}):
```

Comment: I tried doing just that, and not it doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. xD