# Javascript get dimensions image object

Tags: javascript, image, object, width, dimensions

To get the dimensions of an image object, I need to use javascript on my page.

When I `console.log` the image **object** ($img), I get something like this:

```
[<img src="/path/to/image/">]
```

I want to get the original height and width of the original image. I tried using `.naturalWidth`, `.width` but those gave strange results.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure your $img is a correct jquery object. looks more like a simple string to me.

Comment: It isn't jquery, it looks like it is plain javascript

Comment: In your logged output, `$img` appears to be an array.

Comment: "those gave strange results" can you explain? how did you get the image object? can you show your full code?

Comment: I cannot share much more code, since it is spread out over multiple documents and classes. Strange results were things like a bunch of DOM text

Comment: Have you tried in this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome

Comment: @AnandGangadhara I cannot change the creation of the object, I just need to get its dimensions

Comment: Let me ask it in another way: there is an `img` tag on my page in a unique parent. How do I get the dimensions of this image?

Comment: I just want to confirm why is naturalHeight is not working for you, please check this its working here http://jsfiddle.net/cztprdv0/   or like this http://jsfiddle.net/gzqjrbt7/

Comment: @AnandGangadhara when I use `.naturalHeight` on the `$img` I get `undefined`

Comment: What browser are you using to look at your console?

Comment: @Daniel Safari and Chrome, but I think something else is going on. I'm not very strong with javascript objects, so I'm having a hard time finding the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

It is said that webkit may need to load the image first. To do this apply the `onload` first.

```
$img[0].onload = function() {
    console.log(this.naturalWidth);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I don't use things like `document.getElements` ... to find the image. I simply get an image **object** and I have to get the dimensions

Comment: ah ... I see you got it. I was pointing out the array position, but I know how easy a detail can be missed at times ... :-) .. Good luck.

Comment: Your answer made me try the array position and helped me solve the issue. Upvote for that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With your help I got on the right track and solved my problem.

Instead of using:

```
$img.naturalHeight
```

I should have been using:

```
$img[0].naturalHeight
```

Thanks everyone!