# Responsive resize content images

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've got a `.content` element on my website which contains the main content. I want to be able to resize the images when the browser gets resized. So I've made a jQuery function.

First the `setImgData()` function is called. This loops all the images and sets the original size as a `data-w` and `data-h` attribute.

After that the `resizeImg()` is called. Based on the original width and height the image will be resized to maximal the content width (keeping the aspect ratio).

The problem is that the `data-*` attribute doesn't get set. Probably because the `$(this)` inside the load function doesn't point to the content image.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
function setImgData(callback) {
    $(".content img").each( function() {
        var img = $(this);
        var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
        $("<img/>")
            .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
            .load(function() {
                pic_real_width = this.width;
                pic_real_height = this.height;
                $(this).data("w", pic_real_width);
                $(this).data("h", pic_real_height);
            });
    });
    callback();
}
function resizeImg() {
    var cWidth = $('.content').innerWidth();
    var cPaddL = $('.content').css('padding-left').replace("px", "");
    var cPaddR = $('.content').css('padding-right').replace("px", "");
    var contentWidth = cWidth - cPaddL - cPaddR;

    $(".content img").each( function() {
        var imgW = $(this).data('w');
        if( imgW > contentWidth ) {
            var imgH = $(this).data('h');
            var newH = Math.round( ( imgH * contentWidth ) / imgW );
            $(this).width( contentWidth ).height( newH );
        }
    });
};
$(function() {
    setImgData(function () {
        resizeImg();
    });
});
$(window).resize( function(){
    resizeImg();
});
```

Comment: try to give image width and height in % or em. it will re-size automatically upon size of page.

Comment: What is $("<img/>") supposed to achieve?

Comment: @connexo: that gets the original width and height, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/670433/1930721

Comment: @ManojSharma, the content can be changed by the user (with TinyMCE) which gives the elements a `px` unit.

Comment: $("<img/>") in my opinion will not find anything.

Comment: Yes, it will, it makes an img object in the DOM. Then the src attribute is added... look at the link I commented.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the jQuery documentation part where this is explained?

Comment: Also, if you store the jQuery element in each iteration in that local variable called `img` there is no need to wrap it in $() again. You can just go `img.attr.(...)`.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new DOM element for each image?